# Многоколоночный макет - баг с z-index в Chrome

Tags: вёрстка, позиционирование, z-index

Делаю многоколоночный макет на каталоге товаров:
http://shopliga.ru/shop/foroffice/

На hover повесил fadeIn блока с описанием товара. Блок имеет абсолютное позиционирование с z-index поверх всех...
В Мозилле все работает как задумано.
В Chrome - проблема. Не могу добиться, чтобы всплывающий блок был поверх - он обрезается шириной колонки.

Comment: Нашел подобный вопрос в англ. ветке - там есть пример кода на JSFiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321068/chrome-bug-appended-element-does-not-show-properly-in-multi-column-div

Comment: Вобщем, так и не удалось разобраться. Решил просто использовать masonry.